# How to make a pie chart with the elements of a row from a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pie-chart

I would like to simply creat a pie chart with the row 2 of my dataframe. Maybe, you can help.

Here is my dataframe :

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,6,5], 'b':[3,6,9], 'c':[6,9,6]})

I tried :

```
data.plot.pie(x='2')
```

It returns me a error

Comment: `data.iloc[1].plot.pie()`?

Comment: In future, please include the details of the error as this contains very useful information in order to offer help. Also providing the packages that you import make it easier to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To create a pie chart by row, you need to first select that row of data which you'd like to plot, this will return a pandas Series object which you can then use to make a pie chart.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,6,5], 'b':[3,6,9], 'c':[6,9,6]})
data.iloc[1]

[out] 
       a    6
       b    6
       c    9

data.iloc[1].plot.pie()
```

[image: piechart]